# .readlines doesnt seem to work at all in python 3

Tags: python

I am creating a simple basic code as I am gonna use it for learning GUI. So i thought of creating a library sort of code. Its incomplete as this is a main error. Here is the code for it:

```
total_books = open('Total_books.txt', 'a+')

def lend(numeber_of_books, num_days, code_of_book):
    price_per_book = 1
    price_per_day = 2
    total_price = 0
    total_price = price_per_book * numeber_of_books
    total_price += numeber_of_books * (price_per_day * num_days)
    print(total_price, "is the cost.")
    y = code_of_book + "\n"
    lend_books.write(y)
    total_books.seek(0)
    lend_books.seek(0)
    lines = total_books.readlines()
    print(total_books.readlines())
    temp = open('total_books.txt', 'w+')
    for x in lines:
        if x == code_of_book + "\n":
            pass
        else:
            x.append(temp)
    temp.close()

lend(1, 3, "ASFD")

lend_books.close()
total_books.close()
```

Well, in the start of the file there are two files. You can put anything in them for now. As whatsoever the `total_books.readlines()` returns `[]`. As you can see I tried various stuff.

Comment: Do you guys need to know whats going on as my code is quite messy.

Comment: (1) are you sure that `total_books.txt` isn't empty to start with? (2) opening the file in mode `a+` places the cursor at the end, and ignores `.seek()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function/30566011)), which leads to being unable to read anything once something has been written to it (3) Have you tried opening the file twice, separately, once for reading what's _already_ there and once for appending to that?

Comment: @Green that only says writes ignore seek, not reads.

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: I got the problem, I had to add seek(0) before doing  readlines() thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
total_books = open('Total_books.txt', 'a+')

def lend(numeber_of_books, num_days, code_of_book):
    ...
    lines = total_books.readlines()
    print(total_books.readlines())
    temp = open('total_books.txt', 'w+')
    for x in lines:
        if x == code_of_book + "\n":
            pass
        else:
            x.append(temp)
    temp.close()

lend(1, 3, "ASFD")
total_books.close()
```

So you open `Total_books.txt` in append mode; then call `lend`.

In `lend` you `readlines` and assign to `lines`.  You then read it again - and attempt to print that.  But you are already at the end, so the print shows nothing.

Now you open `total_books.txt` again, in a write/overwrite mode.

The rest of the function does some something with `lines` and `x`, but doesn't return anything.  So we don't know if `lines` had anything useful.

And, I don't see any attempt to write to `total_books.txt`.

So between the double readlines, no return, no write, the double open, this code is both confusing, and does nothing useful.

Comment: In the for function, the book that is lent is getting removed from total books and is getting written in the lent books file.